# Logic Around Human Verification on SO Sites

Tags: discussion, captcha

Wondering, at a high level, what is the logic around the human verification interstitial that appears some times when submitting a new question?  I am asking because I am working on a similar system for a site I am working on, and it just happened to me when posting on the UX site (of which i am a member and have posted a number of questions and answers in the past)

Comment: I assume you meant the logic that decides when it appears? If not please let me know, explain better what you mean, and I'll reopen.

Comment: Nice try... bot.

Comment: I am not a bot, and if you look around the network (SE, UX, DBA, LAW and a number of thers under my user, you will see that I am a legitimate active user and this is a legitimate question.